# Ajax Jquery success(response) is not working at first but after refresh it does the job

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm running a PHP code with AJAX and JQUERY. I used these two to run my login form, at first, when I try to log in, it says the email and password is incorrect but it surely wasn't. But after I refresh, I get redirected to the index page meaning the login worked as it also shows the current user on my interface. I can't seem to login properly and have to refresh every single time. What seems to be the problem? Anyone?

**Here is my code PHP/HTML**

```
<main id="main" class="login alert-info">
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="myform bg-dark">
            <h3 class="text-center">Account Login</h3>
            <form id="login-form">
                <div class="mb-3 mt-4">
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Input Email">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Input Password">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-light mt-3">Let's go in!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax/Jquery**

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $('#login-form button[type="button"]').attr('disabled',true).html('Logging in...');
        if($(this).find('.alert-danger').length > 0 )
            $(this).find('.alert-danger').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php?action=login',
            method:'POST',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            error:err=>{
                console.log(err)
        $('#login-form button[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled').html('Login');

            },
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp == 1){
                    location.reload('index.php?page=home');
                }else{
                    $('#login-form').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger">Email or password is incorrect.</div>')
                    $('#login-form button[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled').html('Login');
                }
            }
        })
    })
```

Here is the **function** for login function called from ajax.php

```
function login(){
        extract($_POST);
        $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users where email = '".$email."' and password = '".$password."' ");
        if($qry->num_rows > 0){
            foreach ($qry->fetch_array() as $key => $value) {
                if($key != 'password' && !is_numeric($key))
                    $_SESSION['login_'.$key] = $value;
            }
            // var_dump($_SESSION);
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

I tried removing the errors but no work..

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the AJAX request is made what data does it contain?  Is it what you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: data:$(this).serialize(), is the source of your problem though your email/password are correct but are not being submitted to your ajax.php?action=login.

Instead use data: $('#login_form').serialize()

check the $_POST to find what is being submitted. its redirecting to index not necessarily because login was successful.

Comment: Hey, @David. It shows the right response which in my code 1 = success, 2 = fail. 

It goes correctly, If I login with the right credentials - status = 1, if not, status = 2. 

However, it does not fire the right one where in my case, should log in and redirected to the index page.

Comment: @bacongy: If the response is correct, what specifically happens when you use the browser's script debugger?  Place a debugging breakpoint on `if(resp == 1){` and observe the exact runtime value of `resp`.  What is it?  As you step through the debugger, are you specifically observing that the `if` condition is `false` and the `else` block is executed?

Comment: @ZubairAhmd how can I check?

Comment: @bacongy Very 1st thing is change data:$(this).serialize(), to data:  $('#login_form').serialize() then put console.log(resp) before if(resp == 1){  and then check in your debug windows what is return from server in resp.

redirecting to home page refresh may be due to some other redirect header in your file.